# Save distance between sets of coordinates to new column

Tags: python, coordinates, distance, latitude-longitude, geopy

I have a bunch of coordinates in my dataframe that look like this:

- Start_Lat: 43.11944
- Start_Lng: -75.2932
- End_Lat: 43.12029
- End_lng: -75.2935

I am basically wanting to create a new column in my dataframe that has the distance between the two sets of coordinates in km (see below example).

- Distance: 0.0984

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import geopy.distance as gd
coords_1 = data['Start_Lat'].astype(str) +", "+ data["Start_Lng"].astype(str)
coords_2 = data['End_Lat'].astype(str) +", "+ data["End_Lng"].astype(str)
data['Distance'] = gd(coords_1, coords_2)
```

Sadly this is not working though... Any idea where I am going wrong?

Error message:

[image]

Comment: Please post text as text. Format it using [code blocks or fences](/help/formatting) if needed. Your screenshot is unreadable on mobile

Comment: You seem to have imported the module `geopy.distance` and are attempting to call it. That is not how modules work. There is probably a class or function in that module that you are supposed to call. Have you read the documentation for that module? It should show you how to do this

Comment: The documentation only seems to show how to print the result for one scenario - Not in a column as I am trying to figure out.

Comment: The reason for your error is what I mentioned in my comment above. I am not familiar with that module to be able to tell you if it can handle dataframes, but if it can't, your only option is to build a list by calling the correct function in that module for each pair of coordinates, and assign that list to your dataframe column after you're done calculating distances

Comment: Are you able to actually show me what that might look like please?

Comment: Not at the moment since I'm on my phone, but I suggest you look up a tutorial on lists, loops, and list comprehensions. That should teach you all the concepts you need to try what I suggested in the comment above. I might be able to get to it in the morning

Answer (score 2):

Have worked this out, here is solution for anyone that is looking:

```
data['km'] = data.apply(lambda x: distance.distance((x['Start_Lat'], x['Start_Lng']), (x['End_Lat'], x['End_Lng'])), axis=1)
```